# Insert consecutive dates in sqlite table android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert dates in existing sqlite database.

The table contains one date column that should dynamically update when user press a button. Dates start from current date and continue till last records. Almost 1000 records are present in the table.

Can anybody give some idea how to insert consecutive dates start from current date in table?  I have tried below query but not get desired results.

```
UPDATE example_table 
SET date = date('now', '+1 day')
```

[image: database table structure shows requirements]

Comment: If you want to insert data, why are you trying to UPDATE all the rows to tomorrow's date?

Comment: Table is already created and dates are present there from 2016 dates. i want to update column and enter dates from current to continue, not just tomorrow date. for example 2017-08-07, 2017-08-08, 2017-08-09 continue till last records

Comment: Okay, then shouldn't you be using something like `date(date, '+1 day')`?

Comment: what should i pass to date?

Comment: If i execute this query, then only one record is updated
UPDATE example_table 
SET date = date('now', '+1 day') where id =1
but  i want to update all records

Comment: It is still not clear whether you want to insert or update rows. Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: @CL i update my question

Comment: Please provide a `.dump` from  SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database.

Comment: Are the values from "id" reliably consecutive? Do you know the "id" of the first row you want to update/insert?

Comment: What does this mean? Is that the old or the new state of the DB?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes i know id

Comment: Would you like to answer the first of my two questions, too?

Comment: @CL. this image show required results i want, previously there old dates are presents that should be replaced to new ones

Comment: You mean, there are some rows that already have a date, and you want to change only those dates?

Comment: @CL.dates are already present there . i want to update new dates starting from current date and remove previous dates

Comment: @Yunnosch no idea how to get .dump

Comment: Open the SQLite command line tool on your suitably tailored toy database. Type `.dump`. You do know the SQLite command line tool, don't you? If not I recommend gettting it and playing with it. It sometimes/often provides a more direct view on databases and makes issues visible which are non-obvious through viewers or access languages other than pure SQLite syntax.